# Executing a command inside folders and subfolders with shell script

Tags: shell, find

Currently I'm trying use a single command line to rename all *.mp4.mp4* to *.mp4*.

I've a lot of .mp4 files with these names:

```
103160626309temp1ep10.mp4
103160626309temp1ep10.mp4.mp4

148999555452temp1ep6.mp4
148999555452temp1ep6.mp4.mp4

6802547045temp1ep5.mp4
6802547045temp1ep5.mp4.mp4

335587012366temp1ep4.mp4
335587012366temp1ep4.mp4.mp4
...
```

I'm trying use `find . -iname "*.mp4.mp4" -exec rename -f 's/\.mp4\.mp4\z/.mp4/' *.mp4.mp4 \;` to rename all .mp4.mp4 to .mp4 inside all folders and subfolders but I'm getting this error:

```
Can't rename *.mp4.mp4 *.mp4: No such file or directory
Can't rename *.mp4.mp4 *.mp4: No such file or directory
Can't rename *.mp4.mp4 *.mp4: No such file or directory
Can't rename *.mp4.mp4 *.mp4: No such file or directory
...
```

Do you know how can I solve this issue? Thank you.

Comment: What's with the extra `*.mp4.mp4` on the end of your command?

Comment: To be very clear, that suffix is the cause of your immediate issue: When `*.mp4.mp4` is present in an unquoted context *but no files in the current directory match*, it expands to the glob expression itself; and then when `find` ran a copy of `rename`, it put that glob itself as a literal string on the command line to `rename`, hence your error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no good reason to use the `rename` command at all; just directly rename your matches.

```
find . -name '*.mp4.mp4' -execdir sh -c 'for f; do mv -- "$f" "${f%.mp4}"; done' _ {} +
```

...or even...

```
while IFS= read -r filename; do
  mv -- "$filename" "${filename%.mp4}"
done < <(find . -name '*.mp4.mp4' -print0)
```

---

That said, to explain *why* you got your error: Assuming there are no `*.mp4.mp4` files in the directory where you run the command,

```
find . -iname "*.mp4.mp4" -exec rename -f 's/\.mp4\.mp4\z/.mp4/' *.mp4.mp4 \;
```

becomes...

```
find . -iname "*.mp4.mp4" -exec rename -f 's/\.mp4\.mp4\z/.mp4/' '*.mp4.mp4' \;
```

...so, every `rename` command started by `find` contains `*.mp4.mp4` *as a literal string* on its command line. This isn't evaluated as a glob (and replaced with a list of matching files) because glob expansion is performed *by the shell*, and there's no shell between the `find` and `rename` processes.